# Replacing the beginning of an array with another

Tags: php, arrays

I need to replace the beginning of an array with a second array, with the second array replacing as many items as it has, but leaving the rest of the original array in tact.

So, for example:

```
   $receiver = [1,2,3,4,5];
   $setter = [10,11,12];
```

would result in [10,11,12,4,5]

Here is code that currently works:

```
// iterate through the values overwriting the receiver
for ($i=0; $i<count($setter); ++$i) {

    // if the stored width is big enough to accept this value
    if ($i < count($receiver)) {

        // copy the value
        $receiver[$i] = $setter[$i];
    }

}
```

But is there a better way?

Comment: are they always indexed arrays? (keys are all 0, 1, 2....) or sometimes associative arrays? (named keys)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php

Comment: @BeetleJuice, yes, straight up arrays, not associative

Comment: ok. wrote one up for you.

Comment: @BeetleJuice - thanks!  off testing both solutions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it for indexed arrays

```
$receiver = array_slice($setter,0,count($receiver)) + $receiver;
```

[**Live demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/471fc116711edeac39d2cbdcf73b6d7b78d74652)

**How it works**: `array_slice` will cut off the end of `$setter` if necessary to ensure that it's not longer than `$receiver`. Then the `+` operator will keep the left handside as it is, but if `$receiver` is longer, it will append its extra elements to the end of the array on the left.

Comment: yes, that is what I want to preserve the length of the receiver, very cool trick!

Comment: Glad it helped. I made a tweak to improve performance a bit and adjusted the explanation (I use `array_slice` earlier so the server deals with a shorter array as soon as possible).  You won't notice any difference unless you have really really big arrays, but why not be efficient :-)

Answer (score 1):

Function array_splice does what you want

```
array_splice($receiver, 0, count($setter), $setter);
print_r($receiver);
```

**[demo](https://eval.in/607147)**

Comment: This will fail to give the OP the expected output if `$receiver` is shorter than `$setter`

Comment: My understanding is that with that input, the output should be `10 through 14` because in the OP, the final value of `$receiver` array can't be longer than the initial `$receiver` array.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple code of your requirement.

```
// iterate through the values overwriting the receiver 
for ($i = 0; $i < count($receiver); ++$i) {
    if (isset($setter[$i])) {
        // copy the value
        $receiver[$i] = $setter[$i];
    }
}
```